# use a variable to access $_POST

Tags: php, post

I have a form with a lot of textareas.

```
<textarea cols="30" rows="6" id="q1"></textarea>
<textarea cols="30" rows="6" id="q2"></textarea>
<textarea cols="30" rows="6" id="q3"></textarea>
...
<textarea cols="30" rows="6" id="q54"></textarea>
```

Don't ask why we need 54 questions.

I want to print them out but don't want to do it manually.

```
$i = 1;
while ($i <= $countTextareas) {
  $questID = "q" . $i;

  $question = $_POST[$questID];

  echo "Question " . $i . ": " . $question . "<br />";

  $i++;
}
```

The result of that code is:

```
Question 1: <br />
```

Any assistance or even a point in the general direction would be great.

Thanks in advance.

It may not be the most elegant solution but it works...

```
$i = 1;
while ($i <= $countTextareas) {
    $question = $_POST['question'][$i];
    echo "Question " . $i . ": " . $question . "<br />";
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using PHP, you should exploit PHP's nifty feature of turning a name attribute like `question[]` into an array.

So if you had...

```
<textarea name="question[]" rows="5" cols="5">
</textarea>

<textarea name="question[]" rows="5" cols="5">
</textarea>
```

Your `$_POST` would be...

```
question[0] = 'whatever';
question[1] = 'something else';
```

Comment: its not really an PHP Feauture is it? I mean the POST Request is someting[1] = "something", something[2] = "someting else" that PHP then receives that as an array just seams logical

Comment: Well logical, but it does make the array automatically.

Comment: No. An id can't contain the characters `[` or `]` and is never submitted to the server.

Comment: I don't get how you would iterate through the question array to echo them.
  $question = $_POST['question'];
  $i = 1;
  while ($i <= 54) {
  echo "Question " . $i . ": " . $question[$i] . "<br />";
  $i++;
}

Comment: @SteWill You don't need to build the key if you do it this way - you don't even need to know the limit (though it'd be nice to `array_slice()` it for security). You just iterate through the name `question` and subscript each member. Once you figure it out, it is very handy :)

Answer (score 2):

How about good old `foreach`?

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    echo 'Question '.$key.': '.$value.'<br />';
}
```